# Need proper format in code

Tags: actionscript-3, colors

I am putting in a code that when the user presses a particular button on the keyboard then that color will paint an object on the the flash stage; but it doesn't work - here is my code:

```
if (e.keyCode == "G".charCodeAt()) { 
   colorNumber = #04FA00;   
} else if  (e.keyCode == "H".charCodeAt()) {    
    colorNumber = #CA00E3; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If e is a KeyboardEvent, you may use `e.charCode() == 'G'`.

Answer (score 0):

Hex numbers for colors are written as "0x000000" and not "#000000". So you would write:

```
colorNumber = 0x04FA00;
```

If you use

```
e.charCode == "G".charCodeAt(0);
```

You would need to press shift-g for it to work. Otherwise use

```
e.charCode == "g".charCodeAt(0);
```